# PHPExcel Check if sheet exists

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using phpExcel, and I can't find anything to check if a sheet exists. What I would like to accomplish is something like this:

```
if(!$excel->sheetExists(1)){
    $excel->createSheet(1);
    $sheet = $excel->setSheet(1);
}
// Do some stuff with the sheet
```

So. My question: How can I check if a sheet exists?

**Edit**

Would this work?

```
try{
    $sheet = $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $excel->createSheet(1);
    $sheet = $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you simply want to know whether a sheetexists at index 1, then

```
$sheetCount = $excel->getSheetCount();
```

will return a count of the worksheets. As sheets are indexed incrementally from 0, then a sheet at index 1 will only exist if the count is 2 or more.

If you want to know whether a named sheet exists, then

```
$sheetNames = $excel->getSheetNames();
```

will return an array of sheet names (indexed by their index position), and you can then test using in_array();

The

```
$excel->getSheet()
```

method will throw an exception if the requested sheet (by index) doesn't exist, so wrap it in a try/catch block would be another approach

```
$excel->getSheetByName()
```

returns a NULL value if the named worksheet doesn't exist

Comment: I updated my question with a try catch. Its not the same as the `getSheet` but it is similar.

Comment: It would work, yes.... one of the great things about open source libraries is that you can actually look at the code and see yourself what it does

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a sheet exists by name with the method [sheetNameExists($pSheetName)](http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/php_excel/html/class_p_h_p_excel.html#a366496644a8542dea7d1ecb017aa6452).

Answer (score 1):

`getSheet($sheetNumber)` is how you check if a sheet exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code will also work:

```
try {
        $objWorksheet =  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1); 
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Sheet is not exists!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sheet=$excel->getSheet(1);
// or you can get sheet by name $sheet=$excel->getSheetByName("Sheet1");
if(!empty($sheet)&&is_object($sheet)){
      //sheet already exist
}else{
      //sheet does not exist. Write your code here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"TO KNOW THE PRESENT ACTIVE SHEET NUMBER(INDEX)"
$this->activeSheet->getActiveSheetIndex()

NOTE: 
$loadExcel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("excelSheetName.xlsx");
$this->activeSheet=$loadExcel;