# Is there any way to count total pages of each excel sheet by php?

Tags: php, excel

I have excel file with several sheets, and I need to know how many pages per each sheet. 
Thank you

Comment: can you tell me which php library you are currently using or supposed to use to make it work ?

Comment: Additionaly, you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365599/phpexcel-check-if-sheet-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel Check if sheet exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365599/phpexcel-check-if-sheet-exists)

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave I'm using Phpexcel

Comment: My question is how to count total pages of each sheet. I know how to get total sheets. But I want to total page/ sheet. Thank you

Comment: @Tina total page of each sheet ? did not get you.. you mean number of rows per sheet ?

Comment: If so then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562527/how-to-find-out-how-many-rows-and-columns-to-read-from-an-excel-file-with-phpexc

Comment: @Mittul At TechnoBrave It's not mean number of rows per sheet. Because in some cases user can set format of sheet like 50 rows/page, but in another sheet user can set up to 100 rows per page.

Answer (score 0):

When the Excel file view is set on **Page Break Preview**, the pagination becomes visible. I think that this is what you need.

The pagination depends by the **installed printer** on that machine, the **Paper Size** set for the sheet and if any additional **page breaks** that are set for the sheet.

There is no such a function that returns the number of pages. MS Excel doesn't store such information inside the Excel file format.
You can write function that interpret the bellow elements. You must also take care of how many rows fit in Paper Size height (each row height has a role) and how many columns fit in Paper Size width (each column width has a role).